# PNG Premultiplied Alpha, iOS Simulator vs iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, glkit

I use `GLKTextureLoader` to load a 32bit PNG (created in GIMP). The `GLKTextureInfo` returned is showing `GLKTextureInfoAlphaStateNonPremultiplied` for the `alphaState` on both the simulator and iPad. Experimenting with `glBlendFunc` and GLKTextureLoader I can get it work on the iPad or simulator, but not both!

With no options to GLKTextureLoader, and with the following blend func:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I get on the iOS Simulator (notice the glow on the text is bright)

[image]

And on a 4th iPad (notice the glow on the text is dark)

[image]

Why the difference? The `alphaState` is the same. What could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on an [Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8314057#8314057).

> I have the exact same problem. XCode will convert PNG images so that the header chunk is CgBI (instead of IHDR), and that confuses 3rd party libs like libpng, since a character in Apple's header indicates that the data is in a private format. This operation only takes place for the target device - the simulator is unaffected. There are 4 ways to work around the issue (from easiest to hardest).
>
> 1) Rename your images to something else (eg. .ppng), and the XCode packaging tool will ignore your file.
>
> 2) According to the following link (http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES1xMBX.asp), you need to add the following build settings defintion for each target. IPHONEOPTIMIZEOPTIONS=-skip-PNGs I'm embaressed to say that I still haven't figured out where in XCode project settings to add this.
>
> 3) Teach your PNG decoder to handle Apple's CgBI format.
>
> 4) Use the Cocoa UIImage classes or the Texture2D.m class.

**EDIT:** In "Packaging" of "Build Settings" I have found a "Compress PNG Files" option that defaults to "Yes".

Comment: What I still don't understand, though, is why the output differs between device and simulator. Shouldn't the "Compress PNG Files" option affect both environments?